# Get JSON attribute value by paasing attribute name via "var" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

In json can we get  attribute value by passing variably value . Means

It works for me  when "name" attribute exists in my "returnData" json object

```
              // It works 
               var getColValue= returnedData[0].name
```

but it give undefined error

```
              // It Not works 
               var refVar ="name";
               var getColValue= returnedData[0].refVar;
```

Comment: yeah, if returnedData doesn't have refVar property, you try to access it then you will receive "undefined" value. To make it work, you can try returnedData[refVar] http://jsfiddle.net/wsyCP/2/

Answer (score 2):

Use square bracket notation:

```
returnedData[refVar];
```

In other words, these two are basically equivalent:

```
returnedData["name"] === returnedData.name
```

Note that, using square-bracket notation allows you to set/get property names that wouldn't be valid with the dot notation.  Eg, `returnedData.some-prop` is not a valid Javascript object, but `returnedData["some-prop"]` is.

Comment: What kind of properties wouldn't be valid JSON? `some-prop` is a valid key in JSON. Your example, while technically true, is unrelated to the preceding statement. FTFY

Comment: @JanDvorak: He probably meant invalid (well, sort of) JS.

Comment: @Blender yes, thanks for translating my mumbo jumbo into correct English :(

Answer (score 2):

```
var getColValue= returnedData[refVar];
```

should work. Please give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for replay ...I have edit my Question .Can you please provide some solution according it.

Comment: @user1905838 the same as before: `returnedData[0][refVar]`